# style.css is not changing font - looks like hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I am having a really tiny problem with my CSS. My text does not look very good at all. I used nearly the same styling (added more css and java effects) that I did on other buttons (the other buttons look great). It seems like it is completely ignoring my styling as far as text goes.

My text looks like it's on the top, and underlined with none of the shadowing or styling that I added... Here is my style.css:

```
    .ib-container{
        position: relative;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }
    .ib-container:before,
    .ib-container:after {
        content:"";
        display:table;
    }
    .ib-container:after {
        clear:both;
    }
    .ib-container article{
        -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
        background-color: #dd4814;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
        -webkit-border-radius:6px;
        border-radius:12px;
        color:#ffffff;
        border:1px solid #dd4814;
        font-family:Ubuntu, sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
        height: 65px;
        width: 65px;
        padding:6px 6px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #dd4800;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: 
        opacity 0.5s linear, 
        -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out, 
        box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 
        opacity 0.5s linear, 
        -moz-transform 0.5s ease-in-out, 
        box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 
        opacity 0.5s linear, 
        -o-transform 0.5s ease-in-out, 
        box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: 
        opacity 0.5s linear, 
        -ms-transform 0.5s ease-in-out, 
        box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: 
        opacity 0.5s linear, 
        transform 0.5s ease-in-out, 
        box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        display:inline-block
    }

    .ib-container article p{
        -webkit-transition: 
        opacity 0.2s linear, 
        text-shadow 0.7s ease-in-out, 
        color 0.7s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 
        opacity 0.2s linear, 
        text-shadow 0.7s ease-in-out, 
        color 0.7s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 
        opacity 0.2s linear, 
        text-shadow 0.7s ease-in-out, 
        color 0.7s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: 
        opacity 0.2s linear, 
        text-shadow 0.7s ease-in-out, 
        color 0.7s ease-in-out;
        transition: 
        opacity 0.2s linear, 
        text-shadow 0.7s ease-in-out, 
        color 0.7s ease-in-out;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    /* Hover Style for all the items: blur, scale down*/
    .ib-container article.blur{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
        -o-transform: scale(0.9);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9);
        opacity: 0.7;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

    /* Hover Style for single item: scale up */
    .ib-container article.active{
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
        transform: scale(1.05);
        z-index: 100;   
        opacity: 1;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Here is my html... If I am not being clear enough about what I mean - let me know... basically it just looks unstyled.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:10pt;
        margin:10px;
        background-color:#000000;
        background-image:url('http://www.wallsave.com/wallpapers/2560x1600/fedora/377491/fedora-ubuntu-heavy-metal-distrotest-377491.jpg');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        background-position:-1750px; 
        }
    a {
        color:white;
        }

    </style>
    <style>
    body{font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif; }</style><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold&subset=Latin">

        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
            <meta name="description" content="Item Blur Effect with CSS3 and jQuery - Using Box Shadows, Transform and Transitions" />
            <meta name="keywords" content="blur, css3, transition, jquery, box shadow, text shadow, articles, scale, transform, animation" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
            <script src="js/modernizr.custom.34978.js"></script>    
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <section class="ib-container" id="ib-container">
                    <article>

                            <a target="_blank" href="http://mail.xxx.com/~bcluff/knowledge/support/">home.</a>
                    </article>
                    <article>

                            <a target="_blank" href="http://gmail.com/">gmail.</a>
                    </article>
                    <article>

                            <a target="_blank" href="http://knowledge.xxx.com/">knowledge.</a>
                    </article>
                    <article>

                            <a target="_blank" href="https://utopia.xxxasp.com/login.php?redirect_location=https%3A%2F%2Futopia.xxxasp.com%2F">utopia.</a>
                    </article>
                    <article>

                            <a target="_blank" href="https://webmail.xxxasp.com/plugins/make_pass/makepass_prompt.php">password.</a>
                    </article>
                    <article>

                            <a target="content" href="http://mail.xxx.com/~bcluff/knowledge/support/extensionlist/">extensions.</a>
                    </article>
                    <article>

                            <a target="content" href="http://ip.xxx.com/read_sites.php">viewsites.</a>
                    </article>
                    <article>

                            <a target="_blank" href="http://mail.xxx.com/~bcluff/knowledge/support/oldsite">classic view.</a>
                    </article>
                </section>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {

                    var $container  = $('#ib-container'),
                        $articles   = $container.children('article'),
                        timeout;

                    $articles.on( 'mouseenter', function( event ) {

                        var $article    = $(this);
                        clearTimeout( timeout );
                        timeout = setTimeout( function() {

                            if( $article.hasClass('active') ) return false;

                            $articles.not( $article.removeClass('blur').addClass('active') )
                                     .removeClass('active')
                                     .addClass('blur');

                        }, 65 );

                    });

                    $container.on( 'mouseleave', function( event ) {

                        clearTimeout( timeout );
                        $articles.removeClass('active blur');

                    });

                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `style.css` is being included?

Comment: yes... That is what this line is for:         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

Comment: Yes but are you sure that it's finding the file?  Are you using Chrome?  When you open the console does it display a 404 error for that file?  Maybe it should be `/css/style.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you're styling the paragraph tags but don't have any:

```
.ib-container article p {}

<article>
  <a target="_blank" href="http://mail.sicom.com/~bcluff/knowledge/support/">home.</a>
</article>
```

Also, anchor's get special styling from the browser, so you'll actually need to specify that you want your links styled. This will do the trick, but if you have other stuff on the page, you may want to up the specificity a little.

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #bada55;
    /* the next 3 lines make the link fill  
       the container, so it's all clickable */
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    /* set this to the desired height of the  
       button to center the text vertically,  
       vertical-align: middle doesn't work... */
    line-height: 20px;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: This is also equally correct. Can you help with  1. My text centered in the middle of my button. 2. The whole button to be clickable, instead of just the text. Double points if you can answer this for me. The new div looks like this: .ib-container article a { text-decoration: none; text-align: center; vertical-align:middle; }?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something like this:

```
.ib-container article a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You need a CSS rule that's more specific than the browser's own style for links (text-decoration: link)

Comment: Cheers for the answer - This does the trick (mostly). I still can't get 2 things: 1. My text centered in the middle of my button. 2. The whole button to be clickable, instead of just the text. Double points if you can answer this for me. The new div looks like this: .ib-container article a {
    text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align:middle;
}